# xelatex multilingual book with framed pages

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, memoir, backgrounds

I am compiling a multilingual book (Arabic+English), ~1400 pages, using the `memoir` class, and have been trying to frame each page with a simple black border using the following:

```
    \usepackage{background}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate some text

    \SetBgScale{1}
    \SetBgColor{black}
    \SetBgAngle{0}
    \SetBgOpacity{1}
    \SetBgVshift{-4}
    \SetBgContents{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \draw (0.55\textwidth,10) -- (0.55\textwidth,0.52\textheight) -- (0.4\textwidth,0.52\textheight);
    \draw (-0.55\textwidth,10) -- (-0.55\textwidth,0.52\textheight) -- (-0.4\textwidth,0.52\textheight);
    \draw (-0.55\textwidth,-10) -- (-0.55\textwidth,-0.52\textheight) -- (-0.4\textwidth,-0.52\textheight);
    \draw (0.55\textwidth,-10) -- (0.55\textwidth,-0.52\textheight) -- (0.4\textwidth,-0.52\textheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \pagestyle{empty}
```

The border seems Ok, but I get random empty pages with missing content. I have no idea what is causing this behaviour - I've tried `scrpage2` as well, but to the same effect.

Any help will be much appreciated - many thanks for reading.

p.s. I am using TeXLive 2010.

Comment: The best way to figure out 'what is causing this behaviour' is to construct and post a complete minimal example that demonstrates the problem.  That way, either you will figure it out yourself, or someone else will try to come up with a solution.